# Using Biopython to Retrieve Isoform Sequences of a Swissprot Entry?

Tags: python, biopython

If I have a protein with isoforms, and I'd like to retrieve the sequence of each one, how might I go about doing this?

```
from Bio import ExPASy
from Bio import SwissProt

accessions = ["Q16620"]

handle = ExPASy.get_sprot_raw(accessions)
record = SwissProt.read(handle)
```

This example from the biopython tutorials will retrieve the sequence of the first isoform with `record.sequence`.

I've found simply making a list of accessions to iterate through in the form of the isoform entries listed on uniprot`["Q16620-1", "Q16620-2", "Q16620-3", ...]` does not work.

Comment: Does it have to be BioPython or would any other API and Python work as well?

Comment: Any API welcome, I assumed BioPython would be the likely interface. I'm also not limited to the types of full-bodied record that's retrieved above. Retrieving a fasta file would work just fine for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [Proteins API](https://www.ebi.ac.uk/proteins/api/doc/#!/proteins/getEntriesForIsoforms) of EBML-EBI and a few lines of Python code.

This will give you only the sequence as a string, not as a fully fledged BioPython object.

```
import requests
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

accession = "Q16620"

# a dictionary storing the sequence of your isoforms, key: accesion number, value: sequence
isoforms = dict()

# make a call to EBI API
r = requests.get('https://www.ebi.ac.uk/proteins/api/proteins/{}/isoforms'.format(accession))

# parse the returned XML
uniprot = ET.fromstring(r.text)

for isoform in uniprot:
    # get the sequence
    seq = isoform.find('{http://uniprot.org/uniprot}sequence')

    # get the accession number
    iso_accession = isoform.find('{http://uniprot.org/uniprot}accession')

    # add the values to the dictionary
    if seq.text and iso_accession.text:
        isoforms[iso_accession.text] = seq.text
```

Comment: As `uniprot.getchildren()` is deprecated and will be removed, use `list(uniprot)` instead now.

Comment: @BrianWiley: Thanks for noticing! I updated the answer.